# Insert data from a csv file not in a tabular way

Tags: csv, latex

I have a csv file with one row only.

I need to load some of the column values in a TeX file but I've been struggling to do so.

The csv file looks like this:

```
Email,ISTITUTION,ISTITUTION NAME,ADDRESS,CITY
example@email.com,High School,Whatever name,whatever address,New York
```

What I need is to just load those fields, not in a table, singularly throughout the TeX file.

Something I tried but did not work:

```
\csvnames{temp list}{ISTITUTION=\ISTITUTION,ADDRESS=\ADDRESS,CITY=\CITY}

\csvreader[temp list]{temp.csv}{}{\ISTITUTION}%
```

Thanks to all for some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by myself:

```
    \csvnames{my names}{ISTITUTION=\ISTITUTION,ADDRESS=\ADDRESS,CITY=\CITY}
    
    \csvreader[my names, late after line=\\, late after last line=]%
      {temp.csv}{}{%
The istutution is \ISTITUTION located in \ADDRESS}
```